# Determining an effect of a seatbelt enforcement and a public outreach program in a town

Tags: chi-squared-test

We conducted a seat belt use observation study in two similar sociodemographic towns with different media markets. We sampled two towns and measured outcomes in a pre and post format.  One town was a control site. The other was the treatment site. The treatment site police department conducted an enforcement and public outreach program. Over 3,000 seat belt observations were collected in each town pre and post. The treatment site went from 85.6 percent to 91.2 percent increase in belt use...the control site went from 87.7 to 85.2 percent. What statistical analysis can I use to determine the effect of the treatment program?

Comment: Looks like you didn't finish writing the question?

Comment: The control site went from 87.7 to 85.2 percent..I want to determine if there was a significant difference with the treatment site and include the control data as part of the calculation

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! There doesn't seem to be a question here. Please edit to make it clear what you're asking - & see http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info.

Comment: Should I use a chi square analysis to determine the differences between the treatment and control site pre and post intervention results?  I can easily do a chi square test with just the treatment site before and after data but what is the formula to include the control site data with the calculation?

Comment: This paper may be interesting *A comparison of statistical methods in interrupted time series analysis to estimate an intervention effect*, 2013, Wang, Grzebietaa and Olivier.... http://acrs.org.au/files/arsrpe/Paper%2083%20-%20Wang%20-%20Research%20Methods.pdf

Comment: @DJohnson ITS is useful with multiple measurements over time, it's particularly useful when there's no control site. The approach is somewhat more complicated with some sites receiving control if there are multiple time points. If there are two time points (pre/post), the ITS is a bit simplified, like saying you're fitting a regression model when it's actually a t-test, they are technically equivalent, but the latter conveys to the reader correctly the nature of the data.

Answer (score 2):

A great review of statistical methodology for policy evaluation can be found in "Analysis of longitudinal data to evaluate a policy change." by French, Heagerty 2008. Although most of the methods extend to multiple sites (like 50 US states) or several time periods (like 20 quarters pre/post).

Your example can be seen as a special case of either scenario. You have a treatment group and a control group, and the basic question is: did the proportion experiencing an event at one site *decrease* relative to the proportion experiencing the event at the other site.

I assume this is a cluster longitudinal design without replicates. Replicates, in this case, would mean knowing whether the specific individual *at each site* was sampled for seatbelt use, which isn't the case here.

With 2 sites, 2 time periods, and balanced design, these data are amenable to a difference-in-differences design using logistic regression. You would fit a binary effect for pre-post and a binary effect for site, *as well as their product* and test this against a simpler model which only controls for a pre-post indicator and a site indicator. The complex model is a saturated model, perfectly predicting the observed seatbelt proportion at both sites. The simpler model makes an assumption, under the null hypothesis, that the odds of seatbelt use over time are proportional for the two sites. This is the same as saying that the product term in the complex model is 1 exactly.

A likelihood ratio test of these two models directly tests the hypothesis that the pre-post proportion-change at site 1 was different than the pre-post proportion change at site 2.